# Microsoft Power Query | Web Scraping | "422 Unprocessable Entity" error when adding a query parameter

Tags: excel, web-scraping, powerbi, url-parameters

I'm using the Microsoft Power Query Tool to web scrape the Shopify app store. The URL I provide has a query parameter: (https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=scarcity), that being **search?q=scarcity**. When I attempt to scrape, I keep getting the same error:  *"422 Unprocessable Entity"*.

I've tried submitting the URL in its entirety and also breaking it into 2 parts using the Advanced option: *https://apps.shopify.com/* and *search?q=scarcity*, each resulting in the same error: *"422 Unprocessable Entity"*.

I scraped the root domain: https://apps.shopify.com/ and was successful - so I can't imagine there's an issue with headers, cookies, scraping restrictions, etc.

How can I successfully scarpe this URL, with the provided query parameter, using the Microsoft Power Query Tool?

Entry into the power query tool:
[image]

Resulting error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `Accept` header with `text/html, application/xhtml+xml`.  This will get you passed the 422 error.